# Pytorch Custom Loss Function with If Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, pytorch, loss-function

I am trying to create a custom loss function in Pytorch that evaluates each element of a tensor with an if statement and acts accordingly.

```
def my_loss(outputs,targets,fin_val):
    if (outputs.detach()-fin_val.detach())*(targets.detach()-fin_val.detach())<0:
        loss=3*(outputs-targets)**2
    else:
        loss=0.3*(outputs-targets)**2
    return loss
```

I have also tried:

```
def my_loss(outputs,targets,fin_val):
    if torch.gt((outputs.detach()-fin_val.detach())*(targets.detach()-fin_val.detach()),0):
        loss=0.3*(outputs-targets)**2
    else:
        loss=3*(outputs-targets)**2
    return loss
```

In both cases, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because the condition you are passing to the `if` statement is not a boolean but a tensor of booleans. Just check what's the nature of `(outputs.detach()-fin_val.detach())*(targets.detach()-fin_val.detach())<0`, it is a tensor!

What you should be looking to do instead is handling this in vectorized form. You can use [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html) which is built for this use:

```
torch.where(condition=(outputs - fin_val)*(targets - fin_val) < 0,
            x=3*(outputs-targets)**2,
            y=0.3*(outputs-targets)**2)
```

This will return a tensor of "`x`s" and "`y`s" based on the point-wise condition tensor `condition`. Then, you could average it depending on your needs to get an actual loss value.